# Trigger, no inserting

Tags: mysql, triggers

Error

SQL query: Documentation

```
CREATE TRIGGER `triggers_div` AFTER INSERT ON `produits`
FOR EACH
ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `div_extension` ( `devID` )
SELECT new.devID
FROM `produits`
WHERE new.depID =1;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 5

Can somebody help me?

Comment: your missing an END; though im not sure thats whats causing it

Comment: I m missing an END when I copy this question. regards.The problem is not the END; some body can help me

Comment: Thank you exussum. I see my problem...

Answer (score 0):

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `triggers_div` AFTER INSERT ON `produits`
FOR EACH
ROW
BEGIN

// SOME CODING HERE....

END ;$$
DELIMITER ;

It s work now when I add the DELIMITER like this DELIMITER $$ and not like this DELIMITER$$.